# React - When debugging in chrome, get a 'document not defined' error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, react-native

I'm trying to debug a React Native iOS project in Chrome, and I get a stack trace stating `document is not defined`. When I disable chrome debugging, the app works fine. I'm using react-native 0.14.2 in my package.json. When I try to enable debugging for any of the sample apps, I get the same error in chrome. I simply checked out the react framework from github, so I'm not using the 'react native' commands. Any ideas what could be wrong here? Below is the red box for how my screen looks when 'Chrome Debugging' is enabled. React redbox image below. Thanks!

When I check the the stack trace in chrome debugging this is the line it throws up on:

```
require("react-native/Examples/ViroSample/ViroSampleApp.ios.js");
```

Here is the full stack trace:

> Document is not defined
> handle Exception @ ExceptionsManager.js:63
>   handleError @InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:80
>   ErrorUtils.reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:28
>   requireImpl @ require.js:31
>   require @ require.js:21
>   (anonymousfunction)@ViroSampleApp.ios.js.js:1
>   messageHandlers.executeApplicationScript @ debuggerWorker.js:18
>   onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:42

**Update**
The offending code seems to be the following in ReactErrorUtils.js that is part of the react-haste module:

```
if (__DEV__) {
  /**
   * To help development we can get better devtools integration by simulating a
   * real browser event.
   */
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof window.dispatchEvent === 'function' &&
      typeof Event === 'function') {
    var fakeNode = document.createElement('react');
    ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback = function(name, func, a, b) {
      var boundFunc = func.bind(null, a, b);
      fakeNode.addEventListener(name, boundFunc, false);
      fakeNode.dispatchEvent(new Event(name));
      fakeNode.removeEventListener(name, boundFunc, false);
    };
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you forgot the image?

Comment: I linked to it, not sure why it's not showing up in the question itself.

Comment: Can you post some of your code referenced in the image?

Comment: Something to consider is, as [this article](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/146#issuecomment-71919779) shows if you are pre-rendering or running server-side there is no document object available.

Comment: Hi CalebB, thanks, I'm not doing either, I'll check out the article. Why would debugging in chrome cause this? The app works fine when I don't enable Chrome debugging. The code seems to barf before it hits any my application code. I've added the stack trace I'm getting from Chrome if that helps. I can add my javascript app code, but the app doesn't seem to even get that far.

Comment: `I'm using react 0.14.2` - is that React or React Native? If it's React, then you shouldn't use that, as React Native has it's own built-in "version" or React.

Comment: I've been using react-native 0.14.2.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug [in former (pre 0.14.2) react-native versions](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4007), if you recently updated reinstalling the node modules (`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`) and cleaning the haste cache (`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*`) should fix this.